# Recursively remove element from tuple

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

having some issues with getting the correct result. I am trying to, by recursion, pass in a tuple of words and an item that is one word. The method should return the tuple minus the item. However I am getting an error that reads 'must be str, not tuple'. Here is what I have so far. Thanks in advance.

```
def filter_sequence(seq, item):
    try:
        if not seq:
            return ()
        elif item is seq[0]:
            return filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
        else:
            return seq[0] + filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Example: 
If I call `filter_sequence(("jelly","butter", "mustard"), 'butter')`

 I should receive the tuple of `("jelly", "mustard")`
I've attempted wrapping the last recursive call in str(), but then I just get a string back. Which I would have to break apart and format, which is not what I want to do.
I should mention that it is my goal to achieve this result with using built in solutions like for loops, while loops, if x in y... etc.

Answer (score 2):

The last concatenation should be a singleton tuple, not an item in the tuple - a string. Also, an equality check is sufficient for matching the item in the tuple with the parameter, you don't need `is` here:

```
def filter_sequence(seq, item):
    if not seq:
        return ()
    elif item == seq[0]:
        return filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
    else:
        return (seq[0],) + filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
    #          ^^^^^^^^^
```

<sub>Note: The `is` check may work for smaller strings as those in your code due to some CPython optimization (string interning), but will definitely not work for large strings and is not guaranteed to work the same way across Python implementations. Therefore, use `==`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
return seq[0] + filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
```

`seq[0]` is a `str`, and you cannot add that to the return value of `filter_sequence`, which (in this line) is a tuple. You probably want to stick `seq[0]` in a tuple:

```
return (seq[0],) + filter_sequence(seq[1:], item)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method may be to try this:

```
def filter_sequence(l, target, total):
     if not l[1:]:
         return tuple(list(total)+[l[0]])
     if l[0] == target:
         return filter_sequence(l[1:], target, total)
     return filter_sequence(l[1:], target, tuple(list(total)+[l[0]]))


print(filter_sequence(("jelly","butter", "mustard"), 'butter'))
```

Output:

```
('jelly', 'mustard')
```